# Django Runserver - moving from running locally

Tags: python, django, server, static-ip-address

I want to move from local host to a static IP address (I have it already) with specific DNS name, I'm confused on how to do that? and how to make my app working just by accessing this IP or DNS names from a web browser? Should any machine install all the requirements like Python, Django, IDE etc? not sure how this will happen. I appreciate the help

Edit: I tried this:

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

from the `manage.py`, that should allow any IP to access my page, however, is that the good way to do it?? Also, how to specify the DNS, and I want a domain name instead of an IP to access the page.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/

Comment: Probably more of a Server Fault question.

Comment: @SunSparc, what you mean

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ is the correct site for this type of question as it involves server administration.

Comment: it's actually part of Django development

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly new to Django but I got my website up and running on PythonAnywhere. It was easy to setup and they provide domain name as `[username].pythonanywhere.com`. I followed this tutorial in order to set it up: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/

The tutorial does it by putting the code up on Github then going to PythonAnywhere and doing a git clone. However, PythonAnywhere allows you to upload your code directly to their servers. After you upload the code you can use a virtual command prompt to pip install the packages you need, such as Django.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: So my case I that we have internal server, and I was given Static IP Address and DNS name, do you think your solution will work?

Comment: Oh okay, I did not know you had a server already. If that is the case, then as long as the Static IP Address is assigned to the server then you should be able to copy your code onto the server. Then create a virtual environment and install the packages you need (Django, etc.) then run `python manage.py migrate` then `python manage.py runserver` to set it up.

Comment: Btw, if you haven't setup a virtual environment before, I recommend going through this tutorial to do it: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/
It's best practice to setup a virtual environment for each of your projects, to minimize the risk of conflicting dependency versions.

Comment: Yes, I have a  server already and the Static IP Address is assigned to the server.. But how to copy my code onto the server? how I can do that

Comment: Will I need something like Nginx + uWSGI or Nginx + Gunicorn, or no because I have my own server with its IP??

Comment: Yes, you will.  There are lots of tutorials how to set them up.  I suggest you try to set up locally on your machine, then after you have learned how transfer to your other server.  It will take a week or so.  Lots to learn

Comment: Django has built-in web server for development ONLY. Eventually, when you want to go to production you will need to use something like Nginx + uWSGI as your web server.

If it's a windows server you can Remote Desktop to the server and transfer your code over.

Comment: @Lelo So Lelo were you able to get it working? Let us know if you ran into any issues.

Comment: Just to clarify, for pythonanywhere, you will not need to setup your own nginx/uWSGI stack. That is all done behind the scenes by pythonanywhere.